# Is it possible to integrate the GPT-3 by OpenAPI inside Unity3D or any game-engine?

Tags: game-ai, gpt, dialogue-systems, integration

My company has full access to beta testing for GPT-3. We wanted to try it for some games or game mechanics within Unity3D. Is it possible to use it for dialogues or with unity scripts?

The Documents of OpenAI does not say anything about this possibility, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OpenAI will release an API for GPT-3, so any developer can integrate it into their application. I don't believe the document for their API is public yet, so we don't know what the final interface will look like, but it's likely to be a simple REST API. In the future, I imagine your developers can take advantage of their API, or alternatively there will be community-made scripts for you to use/copy.

The pricing for using their API is explained [here](https://thenextweb.com/neural/2020/09/03/openai-reveals-the-pricing-plans-for-its-api-and-it-aint-cheap/). Note that they charge per token, which might be important in case your game plans to make live calls to GPT-3 during gameplay (as opposed to mining a huge corpus of answers to build an offline database).

The [use cases](https://beta.openai.com/?app=customer-service) of GPT-3 suggests that you can legally use them for commercial products, although I couldn't find a definitive license or user agreement document.

Answer (score 1):

I found these links so hopefully they help.

```
https://openai.com/blog/openai-api/
https://nordicapis.com/on-gpt-3-openai-and-apis/
```